# Use the count result from another query in where condition

Tags: sql

I wonder how to combine two of my queries.

I have these 3 tables:

**movies**

```
movie_id PK
room_id FK
```

**rooms**

```
room_id PK
seats INTEGER
```

**tickets**

```
ticket_id PK
movie_id FK
```

In this simplified example, a movie only plays in a room and many tickets are sold for each movie.

I want to query which movies still have seats available.

For that I need to check

```
(room.seats - all tickets sold for that movie) > 0
```

If I do this, I get the total of tickets for each movie

```
SELECT movie_id, COUNT(*)
FROM tickets
GROUP BY movie_id;
```

And I would like to use that results in this query are condition

```
SELECT movie_id
FROM movies
JOIN rooms ON movies.room_id = rooms.room_id
WHERE (rooms.seats - [THE COUNT OF THE OTHER QUERY]) > 0
```

Does anyone if it is possible to achieve that?

Thank you in advance

I don't know how to combine two queries, it would be nice to understand how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT movie_id
FROM movies
JOIN rooms ON movies.room_id = rooms.room_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT movie_id, COUNT(*) AS C_M
           FROM tickets
           GROUP BY movie_id) t 
ON movies.movie_id = t.movie_id and (rooms.seats - t.C_M) > 0
```

or : use a quantifier ALL,ANY

```
SELECT movie_id
    FROM movies
    JOIN rooms ON movies.room_id = rooms.room_id
    WHERE  (rooms.seats - 
                         ANY (SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY movie_id)
                              FROM tickets
                              WHERE tickets.movie_id =movies.movie_id)) > 0
```

Comment: next time, show sample data

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume, if data looks something like this
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
select 
  a.movie_id, 
  a.seats as "TOTAL_SEATS", 
  count(1) as "SEATS_SOLD", 
  a.seats - count(1) as "AVAILABLE_SEATS", 
  CASE when a.seats - count(1) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' End as "SEATS_AVAILABLE" 
from 
  (
    select 
      m.id as movie_id, 
      r.seats, 
      t.id 
    from 
      movie m, 
      rooms r, 
      tickets t 
    where 
      m.room_id = r.id 
      and m.id = t.movie_id
  ) a 
group by 
  a.movie_id, 
  a.seats 
order by 
  movie_id asc;
```

**Output of the Query:** 
[image]

If you want **movie_id**'s specifically, for those seats that are available, then query will be as below:

```
select 
  b.movie_id 
from 
  (
    select 
      a.movie_id, 
      a.seats as "TOTAL_SEATS", 
      count(1) as "SEATS_SOLD", 
      a.seats - count(1) as "AVAILABLE_SEATS", 
      CASE when a.seats - count(1) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' End as "SEATS_AVAILABLE" 
    from 
      (
        select 
          m.id as movie_id, 
          r.seats, 
          t.id 
        from 
          movie m, 
          rooms r, 
          tickets t 
        where 
          m.room_id = r.id 
          and m.id = t.movie_id
      ) a 
    group by 
      a.movie_id, 
      a.seats
  ) b 
where 
  b.SEATS_AVAILABLE = 'Y';
```

**Output of the query will be:**
[image]

Queries were tested on Oracle database with the above mentioned data.